# jQuery Library to Create Photo Collage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, photo

I am making a photo collage app and looking for a javascript library to make my collage look like "Life in Landscape" from Path. (It came out 5 days ago.) Here is the screenshot: [image]

I already know that [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), and [jQuery Tiles Gallery](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417) do a similar collage. I already built a solution using Tiles Gallery ([www.vash.co/vital.anna](http://vash.co/vital.anna)) but it cuts images arbitrarily, whereas Path seems to cut them so that the faces are centered.

Also I want video and text to be part of the collage, but none of the above libraries allow for that.

If you can suggest any library that does this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Masonry at least (I would assume the others as well) allows you to use any element you want, like `<div>`, so of course you can use any kind of content including text and video. iframes, whatever. I'm not sure why you would have a problem with that.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Masonry and Isotope don't handle the uniform sizing aspect of things